# Webpack dev server hot reload for pixi js game

Tags: webpack, game-development, webpack-dev-server

I have a project for game in PIXI.JS. I am using webpack as bundler.

Need to know how can i configure the webpack to hot reload for development. I already configured production but it is exausting to always after making some changes to build the project and then run it in dev mode. i am using also webpack-merge.

this is my webpack.dev.js file, i put hot: true and watchFiles for my index.js in src folder but nothing happens when i make changes and save the file.

```
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: {
        myFile: "./src/index.js"
    },
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        static: [
            {
                directory: path.join(__dirname, 'build/js'),
                publicPath: '/js/',
                watch: true
            },
            {
                directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
                publicPath: '/',
                watch: true
            }
        ],
        watchFiles: ['src/index.js']
    }
});
```

this is webpack.common.js file
const

```
path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/js'),
        filename: 'app.js'
    }
}
```

this is

this is scripts in package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  }
```

my project structure is

```
/build
/public
/src
```

I never used webpack as bundler so please if anyone can help me.

I tried using copy-webpack-plugin but did not managed